# Extracting values of multiple keys at once from a Swift dictionary

Tags: dictionary, swift, generics

I was playing around with some possible ways to extract several values at once from a Swift dictionary. The goal is to do something like this:

```
var dict = [1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three"]
dict.multiSubscript(2...4) // Should yield ["two", "three", nil]
```

or this:

```
dict.multiSubscript([1, 2]) // Should yield ["one", "two"]
```

In other words, it seems like it should be possible to implement `multiSubscript()` generically for any SequenceType-conformant subscript type.

However, Swift doesn’t seem to like the following implementation, and the error message isn’t very illuminating:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func multiSubscript<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Key>(seq: S) -> [Value?] {
        var result = [Value?]()
        for seqElt in seq { // ERROR: Cannot convert the expression's type 'S' to type 'S'
            result += self[seqElt]
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

This seems like a relatively straightforward use of constraints on generics. Does anyone see what I’m doing wrong?

For bonus points, is there a way to implement this to allow the use of normal subscripting syntax? For example:

```
dict[2...4] // Should yield ["two", "three", nil]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why `for seqElt in seq` doesn't work (I suspect a bug), but using `SequenceOf<Key>(seq)` in the for-in works:

```
func multiSubscript<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Key>(seq: S) -> [Value?] {
    var result = [Value?]()
    for seqElt in SequenceOf<Key>(seq) {
        result.append(self[seqElt])
    }
    return result
}
```

Also note that `result += self[seqElt]` didn't work; I used `result.append(self[seqElt])` instead.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's interesting that `SequenceOf(seq)` without an explicit type does not work either. (The error message is equally obscure: `Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument of type 'S'`.) Actually, looking at the Swift header, `SequenceOf`'s `init(sequence)` method makes no requirements on the type of sequence passed in - it seems to be perfectly fine to lie about the sequence type, e.g. `SequenceOf<String>(seq)` in this example. Then `seqElt` has type `String` and `self[seqElt]` is invalid, but the `for` loop seems to be fine with it.